# How to pass entire WHERE statement from Python to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

The following code returns error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Python code is:

```
 c, conn = connection()
 query = "SELECT case_Case_Number \
     FROM tbl_case \
     ?"
 c.execute(query, (workflow_eval_statement, ))
```

The workflow_eval_statement is:

```
WHERE case_Case_Number = '23-00000500' and case_Case_Status = 'In Process'   and case_Case_Source = 'Portal'
```

When I use that WHERE statement via a query directly into SQL Server to returns that record correctly, without error.

If I modify the program to hard code the field names and pass the values it works:

```
query = "SELECT case_Case_Number \
    FROM tbl_case \
    WHERE case_Case_Number = ? and case_Case_Status = ? and case_Case_Source = ?"
c.execute(query, (parm_case_id, parm_status, parm_source))
```

Results in no error

I also tried passing the pre-built WHERE clause with double quotes (see below) and get the same error.

```sql
WHERE case_Case_Number = "23-00000500" and case_Case_Status = "In Process"   and case_Case_Source = "Portal"
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Remember that the purpose of the `?` is to do quoting.  Your string will be converted to one large string.  You can certainly do `c.execute(query + workflow_eval_statement)`.

Comment: Though if `workflow_eval_statement` is coming from user input, you certainly shouldn't be concatenating the value.

Comment: That concatenation suggested above is horrifying. That is the very essence of sql injection. There are better ways to do "kitchen sink" type of queries.

Comment: what's wrong with your second attempt? that's how things are done (unless you want to be pwned by mallicious users)

Comment: It's unlikely the OP's second `WHERE` will work, @siggemannen , unless they have quoted identifiers off, and I *hope* they don't.

Comment: @ThomA, i mean the one right under the `If I modify the program to hard code the field names and pass the values it works:`

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense, @siggemannen .

Answer (score 1):

After reading the docs, this is what I found.

According to the [pyodbc docs](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Cursor.wiki) for execute:

> The optional parameters may be passed as a sequence, as specified by the DB API, or as individual values.

And then, according to the [DP API docs](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#id20) fr execute:

> Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to variables in the operation. Variables are specified in a database-specific notation

And then:

> The module will use the **getitem** method of the parameters object to map either positions (integers) or names (strings) to parameter values. This allows for both sequences and mappings to be used as input

So I guess is not possible to pass a WHERE statement as a parameter but it's values.